# How to make items of the same row with the same height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

im using Foundation-zurb to make list of article on my page. But if some article has big name or description it affect on grid and move grid of next level to mess.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">

        {% for article in articeone %}

            <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns nothing_article end">

            ....

            </div>

        {% endfor %}

</div>
```

[image]

So i need that all items of the same level take the heigt of the biggers item. Like this:

[image]

So, maybe some trick of some js-library, that will help me to do it.

Comment: Can you please show your existing CSS? I reckon flexbox is your solution

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom class (i.e. `.myClass`) to your `.row` and use this:

```
.row.myClass {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Remember to [prefix](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) all your CSS for maximum browser compatibility.